# Qual a forma correta de parar um loop "for"?

Tags: javascript, loop

Digamos que eu tenha este loop `for` que funciona com base no meu `array` nome:

```
var nomes = ["Nome 1", "Nome 2", "Nome 3"];

for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
   if(nomes[i] == "Nome 2") {
     console.log(nomes[i]);
     console.log("Stop!");
     break;
   }
}
```

Eu estou parando ele fazendo o uso do `break`.

Está é uma forma correta de se parar um `loop`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Se estiveres a falar de um ciclo `for`:

- o método certo para interromper a execução e não fazer mais nenhuma iteração é `break`.
- o método para saltar uma iteração, não correndo mais código dessa iteração, mas executando as seguintes é `continue`, poupando recursos de processamento.

Se estiveres a falar de um ciclo `forEach` (nativo a partir de ES5) não há como parar o ciclo `forEach`. Uma solução é ter o ciclo dentro de uma função e chamar `return`, aí sim saindo do loop, outra solução é chamar `throw BreakException` dentro de um `try`/`catch`. Pode ser bom em termos de otimização.

Comment: Obrigado pelo complemento sobre o ciclo `forEach`.

Answer (score 7):

Sim. Se você deseja sair de um loop, seja ele um `for` ou qualquer outro, você usa o `break`.

No seu código, você vai logar apenas "Nome 2", depois "Stop", e o seu loop para. Recomendo que você faça o `console.log()` do seu contador fora da condição, para você analisar o comportamento. Neste caso, o código fica:

```
var nomes = ["Nome 1", "Nome 2", "Nome 3"];

for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    if(nomes[i] == "Nome 2") {
        console.log(nomes[i]);
        console.log("Stop!");
        break;
    }
}
```